# Map blocking my screen in Hexxit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I play Hexxit, my map blocks my screen. I can't get rid of it and I can't fix it on settings. Its really annoying because I can't see where I'm going. ![2014-02-03_09.16.13.png]
That's my screenshot. It might not show up, but anyway, please help me with this matter. Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question so the screenshot is shown?  It looks like you didn't upload the image.  [There's a built in way to do this.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kFNxj.png)

Answer (score 2):

The Hexxit mini-map is provided by the [Map Writer mod](http://hexxit.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Writer). There are three mini-map modes: hidden (not shown), normal (circle in top right corner), and large (covering most of your screen). The default control for toggling between these modes is the <kbd>N</kbd> key.

My guess is you've accidentally pressed <kbd>N</kbd>. Press it two more times to get back to the normal mini-map mode.